# Can arduino tell room temperature by voice call using sim900?

Tags: arduino, temperature, ivr, sim900

I'm building a temperature monitoring unit with arduino, LM35 and a 16*2 LCD display. Now I am going to integrate this unit by SIM900A GSM/GPRS module and I get temperature readings by SMS.

Now my question is, can I get those values by voice calling. If I called to the GSM modem, can it tell the temperature readings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all possible values as .amr files or you can break them and play the appropriate files using at commands. Like for 35 you can play sound "thirty" and then "five".

Follow the [AMR playing application note available here](http://system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim900_amr_file_playing_application_note_v1.03.pdf)

Comment: you mean I have to add Sd card module?

Comment: You need to save the AMR files in the simcom flash memory. Please go through that documnet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am unable to find the document. please provide me the link again. thank you

Comment: @dmSherazi check out the last link in my answer ... it might interest you

Answer (score 2):

Apart of having all the messages in PCM files there is also possibility to use **TTS** (text to speech) There are small and compact **TTS** engines out there suitable for Arduino port. Here two I am using (with AVR32):

1. [Tiny Speech Synth by stan 1901](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=50530)

   just port it to your arduino (removing the waveout stuff and just use the buffer as PCM). The only lib it really needs is `math.h` for `sin,cos`. It may need a bit more work to actually make it more comprehensible but its not that bad when tuned the frequencies ... its using `floats` heavily but I think port to integer math is also possible ...
2. [KECAL 1.0 ports for ATMEGA](https://sites.google.com/site/zajimavosti/atmel)

   its much older TTS engine originaly from ZX Spectrum but its a bit less comprehensible especially with low quality reproductors (like buzzer) ... But id does not need PWM or DAC ...

I do not know of any more recent OpenSource TTS engine compact enough for MCU platform all I know of are too big or relaying on SAPI,.NET or other OS integrated stuff making them useless.

The **#1** is simple and commented enough to make changes improving the phonemes. The #2 was heavily optimized for speed and size (it run on ~4MHz Z80) so no way to improve quality there.

Btw there are also IC for TTS out there so that might be even better choice...

**[edit1]**

Take a look at this:

- [Is there any text to speech program that will run on an 8- or 16-bit CPU?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17208/6868)

Among other things I added there very good quality and low CPU demand TTS engine ported from Z80 asm into C++, which can be directly used by MCUs ...